# EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way to restrict that only 2 digits can enter in the `EditText` at the Runtime.

For Example:

If i set my `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` and i am entering the value in it. It accepts the value 123.000000000000. But i want to restrict it like 123.00

Is there any Possible way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the following post, maybe of some help for you:

[Preventing input](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg07900.html)

```
EditText txtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
txtInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt) 
    {
        String temp = edt.toString();
        int posDot = temp.indexOf(".");
        if (posDot <= 0) return;
        if (temp.length() - posDot - 1 > 2)
        {
            edt.delete(posDot + 3, posDot + 4);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add validation to an `EditText` using a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).